# How to get the id of the user who loggedin in a schema.on()

Tags: express, mongoose, postman

I am using mern stack to develop a taskmanagement tool in that we can able to create a organisation similar to what's app group where people who are all members in that group can only see the task allocated in that group. I am using express js and mongoodb for backend in that I want to store the id of the organisation to the user who created that organisation so i used mongoose.pre('save') to store the id to organisation feild which was initialized in auth schema .The problem is when I created data in postman the id is updating to all users .But i want the id to store on the particular user so manually provided the id of the the user from database .now its updating the id to the user id i provided.

```
typ// authModel.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const orgModel=require('../model/OrganisationMdl')
const AuthenticationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstname: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter FirstName"],
    },
    lastname: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter Lastname"],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter Email"],
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter Password"],
    },
    verified: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    verificationToken: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    organisation: {
      type: [String],
      default: [],
    },
    workSpacesID: {
      type: [String],
      default: [],
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Authentication", AuthenticationSchema);
e here
const mongoose = require ('mongoose')
const OrgSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    member:{
        type:[String],
        required:true
    },
    superadmin:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
},{timestamps:true})
  OrgSchema.pre("save",async function (next){
    try {
        const loggedInId='64ba17ce9be686518a8478e8'
        const Authentication =mongoose.model('Authentication')
        await Authentication.updateOne({_id:loggedInId},{$addToSet:{organisation:this._id}})
        next()
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
  })
  
  module.exports = mongoose.model('organisation', OrgSchema);
//auth controoler.js
// authController.js
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const authModel = require("../model/authModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");


const sendWelcomeEmail = async (email, password, verificationToken) => {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "mail.snssquare.com",
    SMTPport: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "careers@snssquare.com",
      pass: "Careers.sns@123456",
    },
  });

  const verificationLink = `http://localhost:5000/auth/verify/${verificationToken}`;

  const mailOptions = {
    from: "careers@snssquare.com",
    to: email,
    subject: "Welcome to our application!",
    html: `<p>Hello,<br>Your account has been successfully created with the following credentials:</p>
           <p>Email: ${email}</p>
           <p>Password: ${password}</p>
           <p>Thank you for registering with us!</p>
           <p>Please click the link below to verify your email address:</p>
           <a href="${verificationLink}">Verify Email</a>`,
  };

  try {
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log("Welcome email sent!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending welcome email:", error);
  }
};

const signup = async (req, res) => {
  const { firstname, lastname, email, password } = req.body;
  const user = await authModel.findOne({ email });

  if (user) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: `This email already exists` });
  }

  try {
    const hashedPass = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
    const verificationToken = uuidv4(); // Generate a verification token

    const newUser = new authModel({
      firstname,
      lastname,
      email,
      password: hashedPass,
      verificationToken, // Save the verification token in the database
    });

    await newUser.save();

    await sendWelcomeEmail(email, password, verificationToken);

    res.status(200).json({ message: `User has been created successfully`, newUser });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};
// *=============================     Login     =========================================================================================//

const login = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  // Check if email exists already, if not throw an error
  const existingUser = await authModel.findOne({ email }).exec();
  if (!existingUser) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: `Email Id doesn't exist. Please SignUp` });
    return;
  }

  // Check if the email is verified before proceeding with login
  if (!existingUser.verified) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: `Email is not verified. Please verify your email first.` });
    return;
  }

  try {
    // If the email exists and is verified, then confirm the password; otherwise, throw an error
    const isPassCrt = bcrypt.compareSync(password, existingUser.password);
    if (!isPassCrt) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: `Password is incorrect` });
      return;
    }

    // Generate JWT token for the user ID
    const token = jwt.sign(
      { id: existingUser._id },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
      {
        expiresIn: "35s",
      }
    );

    // Checking if cookies already exist, if yes then clear the cookies
    if (req.cookies[`${existingUser._id}`]) {
      req.cookies[`${existingUser._id}`] = "";
    }

    // If no cookies present then create a new cookie
    res.cookie(String(existingUser._id), token, {
      path: "/",
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 30),
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "lax",
    });

    return res.status(200).json({
      message: `Logged in successfully and the cookies have been created`,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
    console.error(error);
  }
};

// * ==========================    Middleware   To verify Token *==================================================================================/

const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  const cookies = req.headers.cookie;
  if (!cookies) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: "cookies expired please login again" });
  }
  console.log(`cookies= ${cookies}`);
  const prevToken = cookies.split("=")[1];
  console.log(`prevToken= ${prevToken}`);
  if (!prevToken) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: `Cookies not found` });
  }
  //* if cookies present then verify the cookies *//
  jwt.verify(prevToken, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: `Unable to verify the token ` });
    }
    req.id = user.id;
    console.log(`REQ.id = ${req.id}`);
  });
  //* handover  the control of the code to next middleware  *//
  next();
};
//*=========================== to  getUser details only after the tokens are verified ================================================== *//

const getuser = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.id;
  console.log(`userId=\n ${userId}`);
  try {
    const user = await authModel.findById(userId, "-password")
    console.log(`user data -= \n ${user}`);
    res
      .status(200)
      .json({ message: `User is found having the Id : ${userId}`, user });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json(error);
  }
};
/* ============================== to regenerate token gain and again if the user is logged in  ====================================*/

const refreshToken = async (req, res,next) => {
 try {
  const cookies = req.headers.cookie;
  console.log(`cookies = ${cookies}`);
  if (!cookies) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: `Token has been expired please login again` });
  }
  const prevToken = cookies.split("=")[1];
  console.log(`token= ${prevToken}`);
  jwt.verify(prevToken, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json(`Unable to verify tokens`);
    }
    /*if no error then we clear our cookies */
    console.log(`user.id = ${user.id}`);
    res.clearCookie(`${user.id}`);
    console.log(`req.cookies= ${req.cookies[user.id]}`);
    req.cookies[`${user.id}`] = "";
    /* After clearing the token we need to regenerate the token again */
    const regenerateToken = jwt.sign(
      { id: user.id },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
      {
        expiresIn: "35s",
      }
    );
    console.log(`regenerateToken = \n${regenerateToken}`);
    /*creating new token on server side */
    res.cookie(String(user.id), regenerateToken, {
      path: "/",
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 30),
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "lax",
    });
    req.id = user.id;
    console.log(`Succeccfully get  id : ${user.id}`);
     next()
  });
 } catch (error) {
  res.status(500).json(error)
 }
};
/*========================================== To logout from the page ===================================================================*/
const logout=async(req,res)=>{
  /*clearing coookies will automaticallly logout the user*/
  try {
    const cookie=req.headers.cookie
    console.log(`Cookies= ${cookie}`)
    if(!cookie){
      return res.status(400).json({message :`Cookies expired login again`})
    }
    const token=cookie.split('=')[1]
    console.log(`token = ${token}`)
     jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,(err,decodedToken)=>{
      if(err){
        return res.status(400).json({message:`Unable to Verify Token`})
      }
      console.log(`user id = ${decodedToken.id}`)
       res.clearCookie(`${decodedToken.id}`)
       req.cookies[`${decodedToken.id}`]=""
       res.status(200).json({message:`Logout successfully`})
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error)
  }
}

const verifyEmail = async (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.params;

  try {
    // Find the user with the verification token
    const user = await authModel.findOne({ verificationToken: token });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: `Invalid verification token` });
    }

    // Mark the user as verified and clear the verification token
    user.verified = true;
    user.verificationToken = "";

    user.role = "User";
    await user.save();

    res.status(200).json({ message: `Email verified successfully` });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};

 //===============================   export statements  ==================================================================   *//

module.exports = {
  signup,
  login,
  verifyToken,
  getuser,
  refreshToken,
  logout,
  verifyEmail
};
```

But I dont want the id to type the id manually i want to get the id of particular user who loggedin and want [Mongoodb image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9DuZ.png)to update the organization data to store to that user only
how to get the id of the user in this ref schema on looged in

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).